# Making a quiz and need to change background color based on correct choice in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a quiz for a class and am somewhat new to Javascript. I need to have the background color of the questions alternate, which I have figured out. They also need to change color once each question is answered correctly, so when the correct radio button is clicked, the background color of the question changes immediately, for instance from white to blue. I'm sure it is simple, I just can't seem to figure out where to get started to do it. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. Here is the example of my quiz, as well as what I currently have for the Javascript.

```js
if (jQuery) {
  var checkAnswers = function() {
    var answerString = "";
    var answers = $(":checked");
    answers.each(function(i) {
      answerString = answerString + answers[i].value;
    });
    $(":checked").each(function(i) {
      var answerString = answerString + answers[i].value;
    });
    checkIfCorrect(answerString);
  };

  var checkIfCorrect = function(theString) {
    if (parseInt(theString, 16) === 811124566973) {
      var d = document.getElementById("question1");
      var e = document.getElementById("question3");
      var f = document.getElementById("question5");
      var g = document.getElementById("question7");
      var h = document.getElementById("question9");
      var i = document.getElementById("question2");
      var j = document.getElementById("question4");
      var k = document.getElementById("question6");
      var l = document.getElementById("question8");
      var m = document.getElementById("question10");
      d.className += "correctOdd";
      e.className += "correctOdd";
      f.className += "correctOdd";
      g.className += "correctOdd";
      h.className += "correctOdd";
      i.className += "correctEven";
      j.className += "correctEven";
      k.className += "correctEven";
      l.className += "correctEven";
      m.className += "correctEven";
      $("h1").text("You Win!");
      $("canvas").show();
    }
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quiz">
  <div id="question1">
    <div class="question">
      Which is not a main file type that we use to make websites?
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="a" />
    <label>.html</label>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="b" />
    <label>.exe</label>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="c" />
    <label>.js</label>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="d" />
    <label>.css</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want the colors to change. Can you explain further?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. Basically, once I click on the correct answer of a question, the background color of the question along with the answers needs to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('input[value="a"]').click(function(){
 if (jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
 {
 jQuery('body').css("background-color", "blue");
 }
});
jQuery('input[value="b"]').click(function(){
 if (jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
 {
    jQuery('body').css("background-color", "purple");
 }
```

etc.

2 important notes: 
css("background-color", "blue"), "blue" can be rgb color.
jQuery('input[value="b"]'), is a selector, it is selecting all document buttons with value "b". If you have a lot of b value ratio buttons you might be better of selecting by Id.

Check it working: https://jsfiddle.net/Aschab/d4qmhuq1/

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I was able to edit this and make it work for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use onchange on radio button (this code not tested)

```
onchange="checkanswer(this)"

function checkanswer(ele){
   if(ele.value=="A")
       ele.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   else
       ele.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

but checking answer using javascript is a poor action,
you should check it on serverside, or else, people can use ctrl+u to find the correct answer...